# 'CreateView' object has no attribute 'render_to_response'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this `create view` and it throws the error `'CreateView' object has no attribute 'render_to_response'`

urls.py

```
path(
        "p/<int:id>/food/create",
        views.FoodCreateView.as_view(),
        name="food-create",
    ),
```

views.py

```
class FoodCreateView(BaseCreateView):
    template_name = "food_form.html"
    form_class = forms.FoodForm
    success_message = "successfully created"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Food.all(#####)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "food_list"
        )
```

am I lacking anything with the code?

Comment: Why are you using `BaseCreateView`? use `CreateView`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In newer Django newer Versions, CreateView is inherits with BaseCreateView . AND in newer version render_to_response is also replaced with render

So you should import it like :-

> from django.views.generic import CreateView

After change it :-

Your view should look like this :-

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import CreateView


class FoodCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = "food_form.html"
    form_class = forms.FoodForm
    success_message = "successfully created"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Food.all(#####)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "food_list"
        )
```

Comment: I believe `CreateView` has always inherited from `BaseCreateView`... Which older version of Django had it in place of `CreateView`? Also `render_to_response` is a function it inherits from `TemplateResponseMixin` down the line....

Comment: I think https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/ this should work fine for you .

Comment: It has nothing to do with newer versions.... `CreateView` simply inherits from `BaseCreateView` i.e. `BaseCreateView` is one of the **building blocks** of `CreateView`.

Comment: Changing it to `CreateView` made the code worked. It is still just not clear to me why it isn't working with `BaseCreateView`. Anyways, Thanks for the help!

Comment: `BaseCreateView` is **not replaced** with `CreateView`. It is just the basic implementation of `CreateView` and not meant to be used directly. It needs various methods implemented which are provided by `CreateView` and other ancestors of `CreateView`.